# converting google app engine backend to module

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to convert google appengine backend war (running on 1.93) to module. I have tried eclipse (after reading docs) and maven on how to generate the EAR file. However, I just don't get how it is done. Does anyone have a for dummy EAR file so I can look at. I just don't get the directory structure and what is supposed to be in those xml files. The appengine was easy to use and I was able to get an app running quickly, but then I saw that backend is now deprecated so I am sure I must move to module quickly..... amazon AWS seems easy to use as well but cron job @AWS seems to be a little tricky. I already have cron job working in GAE.

I have been googling and looking at almost all the postings... about to give up and try AWS

thx

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same position and have been experimenting with this for the past week.  I've gotten several "modules" working in an EAR using the GPE with WTP support.  Here are some things that helped me.  I assume you have Eclipse installed with Google Plugin for Eclipse.

Follow the instructions here for using the WTP project format:

[https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/)

It took me a few tries, because I didn't follow instructions exactly.  A couple of things that got me:

a) I didn't create a "default" module and that caused some erratic behavior.
b) When right-clicking on the project there will be Google and Google App Engine WTP commands.  Many of the commands for app engine in the Google menu don't work for an EAR.  Instead use the commands in WTP, such as deploying.
c) In regards to (b) Google->App Engine Settings doesn't work (they should dim out the menu item).  Instead you have to edit the appropriate XML file.

Note that following the instructions pretty much sets up the various XML files for you.  After you get it going, you can open them up and tinker with them.  Not much to them.

Right now I'm going over this to create a backend project:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/

Given that I have a basic EAR with some google cloud endpoints and a simple front end, I don't think it will be difficult to add the backend now.

Comment: I have moved to Amazon within hours BUT I am still looking at how to add a batch process in AWS... Perhaps I should have a look at GAE again. Let me circle back. thanks. I will read the docs again